# UIWebView in iPhone only app displayed on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, uikit, retina-display

I've got a question concerning a UIWebView in iPhone app (not a universal iPhone/iPad) displayed on an iPad. There are some ways to treat the application as a iPhone retina app (960x640), however I can't fing the way to display the UIWebView on the iPad in the same way as it's displayed on iPhone. The whole view and the fonts are blurred, because UIWebView thinks it's not a retina display.

Is there a way to make it think that it's retina display and to render a 960x640 instead of 480x320 scaled up?

UIWebView contentScaleFactor property is not changing anything. The site works perfectly on iPhone 4, with proper fonts and retina images. If I set the UIWebView frame as (0, 0, 960, 640) and scale it down then all content on the site is scaled down as well so that's not the proper way I think.

Edit:
As a content I'm loading a local site, which is perfectly displayed on iPhone/iPhone (retina):

Body setion of a html:

```
(...)
<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Some paragraphs</p>
    <img src="image.png" width=250px height=200px/>     
</body>
(...)
```

Style.css:

```
body 
{
    width:400px;
    height:100%;
}
```

Edit2:
Here is the link to [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLpI5.png) of what am I getting - on the iPad, the iPhone retina UIWebView is displayed like on the iPhone and scaled up twice, what gives blurred result.

Comment: What are you loading on the webview?

Comment: @jcesar I'm loading a local website, sized and positioned for iPhone/iPhone retina.

Comment: I do not understand whether you are trying to simulate or use iPad Retina display.

Comment: Once again: I have an iPhone app, which could be run on iPad1/iPad2. When you are running iPhone app on iPad, it runs in a 480x320 window. You can maximize it to 960x640 window - and in that case it should be treated like iPhone retina app with 960x640 resolution.    However, UIWebView check that iPad hasn't got retina display (which is true) and load content with frame 480x320, which is then stretched to 960x640 what looks teribble.    The question is, how to force the UIWebView to think that it is running on iPhone retina.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you press the 2x button your app gets scaled up and you can't detect this in code.

This is a big miss on Apple part, the app should have run in retina mode when displaying it in 2x mode on the iPad, but that would have ment that you needed to restart the app when it enters the 2x mode.

The retina version of you app will be used for the new iPad, but agin scaling here will just double the pixels.

Comment: I can agree that Apple is not supporting it by default, however if you use some framework that works on pure OpenGl, you can handle it by yourself. That's what I'm doing in the other parts of my application and I thought that there is a way to force UIWebView to display in retina mode as well. Maybe someone has an idea how to cheat on this.  Anyway, thanks for your answer ;)